# Python classes act strangely on Google Colaboratory

Tags: python, class, google-colaboratory

I created the Python class Student on Google Colab. However, for some strange reason, the destructor is invoked prior to initialization for the object Jane, which is baffling.

I have attached the Google Colab output below.

When I tested the same code on 1) JupyterLab and 2) My local machine, I got what I expected output (attached below).

Could someone enlighten me as to why classes behave strangely in Google Colab?

```
class Student:
  name = ''
  section = ''
  age = 0
  def __init__(self, name, section, age):
    self.name = name
    self.section = section
    self.age = age
  def __del__(self):
    print(f"{self.name} is graduating!")
  def print_details(self):
    print(f"Hi, my name is: {self.name} and I am in section {self.section}. My age is {self.age}")


ramu = Student('Ramu',3, 15)
ramu.print_details()
del(ramu)
jane = Student('Jane',1,14)
jane.print_details()
```

Google Colab output

```
Hi, my name is: Ramu and I am in section 3. My age is 15
Ramu is graduating!
Jane is graduating!
Hi, my name is: Jane and I am in section 1. My age is 14
```

JupyterLab and Local Machine ouput

```
Hi, my name is: Ramu and I am in section 3. My age is 15
Ramu is graduating!
Hi, my name is: Jane and I am in section 1. My age is 14
```

Comment: I am getting the second output in colab. Can you check once again after  restarting the runtime

Comment: The only explanation I can think of is the output being out of order with the execution. Also you're probably just playing around, but don't use `__del__` for anything serious. :)

Comment: Thank you @komatiraju032! Restarting runtime fixed it.

Comment: Thanks @MarkM! Also, I am relatively new to Python, but what should I use instead of __del__ for garbage collection?

Comment: Any referenced object in Python is automatically garbage collected when the number of references to it drops to 0. So generally: don't worry about it unless you are running memory intensive calculations.